# How to easily run system shell task / command in Gulp?

Tags: node.js, shell, gulp, child-process

I've considered following options:

use `gulp-shell`: the plugin is deprecated and buggy

use `gulp-exec`: seems to be tied with gulp-streams which I have no use for. I'm not sure how to use this for running single task and authors even claim, that you shouldn't use it for running just one task.

use `child_process.exec` Although this is recommended by authors of `gulp-exec`, the solution seems bad for two reasons: a) stdout and stderr are not printed to the console progressively and are accessible as buffers / strings only after the child process ends. b) if the process produce too much console output, the buffer limit is exceeded and the exec crashes. This means, you shouldn't use it unless you are 100% sure, how much output may your process generate.

use `child_process.spawn` Although little bit verbose, this is the best I found so far:

```
gulp.task('list', (cb) => {
  childProcess.spawn('find', ['/'], { stdio: 'inherit' }).on('close', cb);
});
```

Comment: This is an excellent comparison. Have you tried execSync?

Comment: You mean `child_process.execSync`? Well, that's just sync version of `child_process.exec`, which (I'd guess) will suffer from the same issues as its asynchronous cousin.